# Proguard: NullPointerException in ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource without any of my classes in the stack trace

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, proguard, obfuscation

My app starts without any problem. But while I log in and the next activity is about to start the app crashes with following Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:453)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:204)
    at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:602)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1187)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:706)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1168)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:706)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2718)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1572)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

What surprises me is that none of my classes or an external library appears.
If I keep my whole package, the next activity starts successfully. But then I don't need to use obfuscation either.
Which is strange too:
If I keep my whole package it works fine. But if I keep the two sub-packages (package.name.technical & package.name.functional), it won't work.

I keep a lot of View things, which I found in the internet. For e.g.:

```
-keep class android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView {*;}
-keep class android.widget.Spinner {*;}
-keep class android.widget.ArrayAdapter {*;}
-keep public class * extends android.widget.AdapterView {*;}
-keep public class * extends android.widget.Adapter {*;}
-keep public class * extends android.widget.BaseAdapter {*;}
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}
```

I also keep the activity that should start.

"shrinkResources" is NOT enabled in build.gradle.

Does anyone have any idea why? I'm getting really desperate and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting issue!  Let's dig into it a bit.

First, what's `null`?  Well, there's only [one `toString()` call](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/3e6b337bf448d68996c384bb84cb2afdb08919eb:core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java;l=457;drc=a900cb533f8108399852dc3ad3912c5c1bbcc64c) in `ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource`, so it's got to be that.

That's the item that's returned from `getItem(position)` a few lines up.

`getItem` is simple: it just returns an item from the `List` of objects passed into the constructor.

Thus, your problem is that something about your Proguard obfuscation is causing you to have a `null` item in the `List` passed into one of your `ArrayAdapter`s.  Perhaps an issue inflating models via Gson or other reflection-based deserialization?

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your help, I found the appropriate class, which I have to keep. I had to keep the class that is given to the spinner as a list.

Comment: Yay!  I'm glad it helped, it was interesting to investigate and piqued my curiosity.

Comment: @RyanM Hi, I have this exactly same problem(ditto), but when I keep the String class which I used to pass as a list to ArrayAdapter, it didn't work, still crashing with the same log in the question, what should I do extra to keep in proguard?